# Admob banner ads not showing in my physical device

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated `admob` banner ads in my android app.ads are showing in emulator but not in my physical device.the log cats are  spams like

euler: is urlblocked = false

firewall not null

Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad

Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked internet connection in device?

Comment: yah internet connection is working

Comment: try to change package name application and then checked

Comment: i cannot get it.plz explain

Comment: put u r admob code

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in

```
Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad
Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now
```

This means that the AdView that you are loading ads for is hidden by you or your layout, so AdMob has skipped loading ads for it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion